# Switch enum auto-fill

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I was typing a switch with an enum in VS 2013 and all case statements filled out automatically after I finished the switch. Now I can't repeat it. I was not hallucinating, the switch filled out with all enum options, one per case, automatically. Looked through MS docs for VS 2013 and didn't find it.

I use quite a few enums and this feature will save me a ton of time if I can find what it is I did to trigger it. Can anyone help?

Comment: http://worthyd.com/techblog/index.php/2010/09/visual-studio-c-enum-switch-snippet-blew-my-mind/

Comment: Link  in comment is broken, the fixed link is:
https://worthyd.com/blog/2010/09/visual-studio-c-enum-switch-snippet-blew-my-mind/

Comment: The link URL has changed again. The new link is, https://worthyd.com/blog/visual-studio-c-enum-switch-snippet-blew-my-mind

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Type "`sw`", and then press <kbd>tab</kbd>,<kbd>tab</kbd>.

Comment: meaning....type `sw`, intellisense will pop up prompting you to build a switch, hit tab when that is highlighted and tab again and you'll have your switch statement

Comment: You have to click once you've typed the argument for the switch statement for it to auto generate the case and break lines, at least in the case of an enum.

Comment: VS2019 is still the same

Comment: This answer doesn't have quite enough information.  You have to start typing switch then press tab tab to get the default switch statement template to appear, but then you have to replace the default variable "switch_on" with your enum variable, then press **Enter** twice to generate the switch statements (not tab).

Answer (score 114):

**Notice:** This answer applies to performing the switch/enum autogeneration while also using Resharper.

Using Visual Studio 2013 and Resharper 8.2, the previously mentioned methods do not work. Here's how to actually get this generation to work when using Resharper. Hopefully it will save someone the fifteen minutes I just spent figuring this out.

Performing "sw(tab)(tab)" will only generate the following:

```
switch (nameOfEnumVariable)
{

}
```

Resharper can generate the labels using **Alt + Enter** (if your cursor stands in the switch statement) and selecting **Generate switch labels** as in the following screenshot:

---

[image: Using the Resharper menu to fill in a switch statement]

---

The result looks like this:

---

[image]

---

Comment: That works with VS2010 and ReSharper 8.2, too. Thanks =)

Comment: That did it using VS2012 and R# 8.2. Thanks for saving me a headache.

Comment: Does not work with VS2012 and R# 8.2.3000.5176 for me... "Generate switch labels" is missing, only "options for CS1522..." is present on Alt+Enter. Any suggestions?

Comment: can anyone tell me how is this working, because i need to customize this "GenerateSwitchCases" function ..

Comment: the switch should not have any cases, to get this generation option. It will generate all the possible cases for enum.

Comment: This works with ctrl + enter in VS2015 out of the box without the requirement of Resharper :)

Comment: I wonder if this can be performed automaticallt by R# instead of having to press Alt + Enter and selecting an action first?

Answer (score 34):

The selected answer is mostly correct, you don't need Resharper as other's have suggested (at least not with Visual Studio Professional 2012+).

1) type "sw" then "[tab][tab]" (as `Marvin Smit` said)

Which (as `jmblack` said) will generate something like:

```
  switch (switch_on)
  {
            default:
  }
```

but then

2) you need to select which thing to enumerate on (`switch_on` will be highlighted still at this point).  So type in the Enum (or your variable of the enum type) while `switch_on` is highlited and hit [Enter][Enter].

(I just confirmed this worked on my machine running VS2012, and i'm fairly certain this is the same thing i have done on my other machine running VS2013, and i haven't tested other versions of VS (ultimate/express/etc.))

Comment: Works in VS2015

Answer (score 28):

Visual studio 2017, 2019 - without Resharper:

1) write "switch"

2) press two times TAB, then you will see:

```
switch (switch_on)
{
        default:
}
```

(the switch_on is highlited)
3) retype `switch_on` to your enum variable or type 
4) press ENTER or click somewhere else (pressing TAB does not work), now you should see all the enum items filled:

```
switch (YOUR_ENUM_VARIABLE_OR_TYPE)
{
    case YOUR_ENUM_TYPE.Item1:
        break;
    case YOUR_ENUM_TYPE.Item2:
        break;
    case YOUR_ENUM_TYPE.Item3:
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that you have to press enter twice, but this worked! Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I think what you need is this:

```
sw(tab)(tab)enumVariableName(tab)(downArrow)
```

I tested it and works ( in VS2013 at least).

Comment: Thank you! The other answerd did not work for me, but this one does work!

Answer (score 4):

By default, Visual Studion's snippet works correct. You should type "sw" and then press double "Tab".

If you use Resharper, the snippet doesn't work, because Resharper's snippet has more priority, by default. So, you should turn off resharper's snippet.

Go to "Resharper" -> "Template Explorer"-> "C#" then uncheck "switch". Try "sw" + double "Tab"

Comment: Why would Resharper think its version is better?

Comment: Hmmm... so I unchecked the switch statement, and it didn't allow the double tab to autofill the enums

Comment: Then you can disable ReSharper's built-in Intellisense feature. Go to Resharper menu>Options>Environment>IntelliSense>General and select Visual Studio

Answer (score 4):

I've written a free and open source extension, based on [Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn), for Visual Studio 2015 and 2017, that not only allows to fill the switch case for an enum, but is also capable of adding new cases if enum values (fields) have been added to the enum type definition, or sort the list of cases by value or name.

It's available here: [Enum Case Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-591.EnumCaseGenerator)

This is how to use it:

[image]

Comment: This works well and was the only answer that worked for me.

Comment: The fact that this can be used after the switch is already created makes this the best answer.

Comment: Really nice little time-saving extension for those inevitable times when you have to map enums between boundaries.

Answer (score 3):

VS 2019 + resharper create an empty switch with your variable. Click on first curly bracket "**{**" Then press **alt + enter** You will see **Generate switch labels**. Screenshot below:

[image: Generate switch labels]

Answer (score 2):

Hi I just ran into the same problem, I just found out that when you do:

```
switch(nameofvariable){
  default:
  break;
}
```

when you are filling the variable and you double click on the variable of your choice (the enum) it will give you all the cases