# How to generate switch statement labels on Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I want to generate switch statement labels in Visual Studio Code. I searched Google, the extensions marketplace, and the command pallete, but I didn't find anything. Is this action available?

Comment: MonoDevelop is an IDE, VSCode is a text editor, they're not really comparable, so don't get your hopes up

Comment: Oh, I completely forgot the fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not available.

Visual studio code is a simple editor and hasn't capability like visual studio IDE and can't do this.

In Visual studio 2015 IDE You can generate switch statement labels for enumeration as:
1) write "switch"
2) press two times TAB
for details, read [Switch enum auto-fill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19778108/switch-enum-auto-fill)

Also Resharper tool (integerated with Visual studio IDE) can do the same.

For details read: https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2006/06/14/quick-fixes-help-generate-switch-blocks/

Comment: This feature is available in VS Code if you have enabled Rozlyn Analyzers under Omnisharp setting section.

Answer (score 4):

This works with the OmniSharp extension:

[image]

More info here:
https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/1752