# Automated replacement of numeric constants with equivalent enum values?

Tags: c#, vb6-migration

Some of my C# codebase was originally converted from another language. In a bunch of cases the original was sloppy & used numeric constants where they should have used enums (even though enums were actually defined). That original compiler (VB6) was fine with that.

In the converted C# code however the compiler is not so permissive. So as a quick fix we've just pasted in explicit casts. This results in a lot of code (1000s of lines) that looks like this:

```
case (FooEnum)1:
case (FooEnum)123:
    DoSomething();
    break;

case (FooEnum)3:
    ...
```

While this functions correctly it loses a lot of the readability benefits of enums. Some cases are lumped together like my example, others are just one-off uses of enum values in logic.

What I want, but would be quite painstaking and error-prone to do manually, is to have something automatically update that to look like this:

```
case FooEnum.Car:
case FooEnum.Aeroplane:
    DoSomething();
    break;

case FooEnum.Dog:
    ...
```

I can't think of a search & replace method that would solve this en masse. (Search & replace would work for a small number of cases but seems impractical for 1000s of variations).

Is there any kind of "tool trick" like a Visual Studio refactoring that might exist to solve this? There are a few things which come close (like [Switch enum auto-fill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19778108/switch-enum-auto-fill)) but don't quite fit the need.

Ideally I just want to replace the cast'ed values with real values. If I had to recreate the entire switch statements (or other code using these) even if that were done automatically, it might not be worth it.

Comment: Sounds like you'd have to build yourself an analyzer, but it could be time consuming and not worth it if it's a one-off task.

Comment: @silkfire I've never done that... if there were something similar that could be modified that sounds like a possibility though.

Comment: Analyzers are very powerful, they can save you a lot of time and detect hard-to-find bugs. They're a bit difficult to build though. If you're willing to, though, here's an excellent guide to start you off: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/how-to-write-a-roslyn-analyzer/

Comment: You could do this with a Roslyn analyzer, There are examples, but they won’t be easily modified for what you want. Search and replace also seems like it would be a viable strategy, using a regular expression.  A bit more hands on to do, but potentially quicker since this isn’t an ongoing issue or have a lot of variations or variables.